# date calculation (TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str')

Tags: python

I have a data set as below:

```
        date_time       srch_co     srch_ci
0   2014-11-03 16:02:28 2014-12-19  2014-12-15
1   2013-03-13 19:25:01 2013-03-14  2013-03-13
2   2014-10-13 13:20:25 2015-04-10  2015-04-03
3   2013-11-05 10:40:34 2013-11-08  2013-11-07
4   2014-06-10 13:34:56 2014-08-08  2014-08-03
5   2014-12-16 14:34:39 2014-12-17  2014-12-16
```

And this is the information of the dataset:

```
     <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 100000 entries, 0 to 99999
Data columns (total 3 columns):
date_time    100000 non-null datetime64[ns]
srch_co      99878 non-null object
srch_ci      99878 non-null object
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), object(2)
memory usage: 2.3+ MB
```

What I would like to do is create 2 new columns using the following function:

```
def duration(row):
    delta = (row['srch_co'] - row['srch_ci'])/np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
    if delta <= 0:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return delta

sample['duration'] = sample.apply(duration, axis=1)


def days_in_advance(row):
    delta = (row['srch_ci'] - row['date_time'])/np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
    if delta < 0:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return delta

sample['days_in_advance'] = sample.apply(days_in_advance, axis=1)
```

However, it seems like the date calculation I want to run constantly hits errors. I've searched and found several solutions and tried, but either they would create error or turn the date into inaccurate value.

The methods I've tried to use are such as:

```
#1)
def to_integer(dt_time):
    return 10000*dt_time.year + 100*dt_time.month + dt_time.day

#2)
datetime.strptime(str(row[2]), '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

#3)    
pd.to_numeric(sample['date_time'], errors='coerce')

#4)
sample['srch_ci_int'] = sample['srch_ci'].astype(str).astype(int)
```

I just want to create new column that would calculate the difference of each columns:

```
sample["duration"] = sample["srch_co"] - sample["srch_ci"]
sample["days_in_advance"] = sample["srch_co"] - sample["date_time"]
```

Any tips appreciated.

Comment: From the information we have here, I would assume that simply converting the columns  `srch_*` to `datetime` objects could help.

Comment: Right, I don't know why I haven't thought about that. Thanks! 

`sample['srch_co'] = pd.to_datetime(sample['srch_co'])
sample['srch_ci'] = pd.to_datetime(sample['srch_ci'])`

this worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need convert columns `srch_co` and `srch_ci` [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) first and then use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) for replace values less as `0` to `NaN` (default value of `mask` function):

```
sample["srch_co"] = pd.to_datetime(sample["srch_co"])
sample["srch_ci"] = pd.to_datetime(sample["srch_ci"])

sample["duration"] = (sample["srch_co"] - sample["srch_ci"])/np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
sample["days_in_advance"] = (sample["srch_co"] - sample["date_time"])/np.timedelta64(1, 'D')

cols = ['duration','days_in_advance']
sample[cols] = sample[cols].mask(sample[cols] < 0)
#first value of srch_ci column was changed for NaN output
print (sample)
            date_time    srch_co    srch_ci  duration  days_in_advance
0 2014-11-03 16:02:28 2014-12-19 2015-12-15       NaN        45.331620
1 2013-03-13 19:25:01 2013-03-14 2013-03-13       1.0         0.190961
2 2014-10-13 13:20:25 2015-04-10 2015-04-03       7.0       178.444155
3 2013-11-05 10:40:34 2013-11-08 2013-11-07       1.0         2.555162
4 2014-06-10 13:34:56 2014-08-08 2014-08-03       5.0        58.434074
5 2014-12-16 14:34:39 2014-12-17 2014-12-16       1.0         0.392604
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're subtracting a string from a string. Make sure to convert the column to type 'date' using [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), and then you'll be able to subtract one day from another.

Another recommendation is to avoid for loops and to use vectorized operations, such as pd.DataFrame.subtract(series, axis=0), as that is one of the biggest advantages of using pandas over any simple list.

After you've calculated the difference, then you can turn all negatives into nan by saying

```
dataframe[dataframe['duration'] < 0] = np.nan
```